# Can't change menu bar clock from digital to analog in Monterey

Tags: monterey, clock

I've done the SysPrefs/Dock & Menu Bar/Clock bit of clicking "analog," but nothing changes.

Comment: Haha! My clock was analogue; tried to reproduce your problem by clicking buttons on the Clock settings; nothing happened (stayed analogue); looked away and came back a few minutes later, it had become digital.  And now I can't turn it back to analogue. Grrr!  I think you have found a bug.

Comment: Just wait. Without me doing anything obvious, at some time since yesterday the clock has changed back to analogue. So set it how you want it to be, and it will eventually get there.

Comment: Interesting. I’ll give it another try and report back.

Comment: @ProfT if this solved it, please answer your own question stating this.